# flickr api: how to get relevant image results?

Tags: image, flickr

I am  getting some irrelevant and low (subjective) image quality  from the flickr api.
I notice that sites such as haiku deck use flickr api and they get relevant results

[image: desired flickr search result]

I am using the [flickrnet](https://flickrnet.codeplex.com/) api. Below is the code I am using, along with the results when `query = 'cow'`

```
  Flickr flickr = new Flickr(flickrKey, flickrSecret);

            PhotoSearchOptions options = new PhotoSearchOptions();

            options.SafeSearch = SafetyLevel.Safe;
            options.Licenses.Add(LicenseType.AttributionCC);
            options.MediaType = MediaType.Photos;

            options.Text = query; 

            options.Extras = PhotoSearchExtras.AllUrls;

            PhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotosSearch(options);
```

[image: actual results]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution is to set sort by relevance. default is by date

```
  options.SortOrder = PhotoSearchSortOrder.Relevance;
```

Comment: There is the order by `relevance` AND another field called `accuracy`. Also I usually set `safe_search` to true in case of. (avoid some NSFW, but is not 100% perfect)

Comment: accuracy applies to geographic search. I am indeed setting safe search to true.